# In Light of Deuteronomy 4:15 & John 4:24 how to understand the image and likeness in Genesis 1:26?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, creation, image-of-god

We are initial told that when God created humankind he made him in his image and  likeness.

Genesis 1:26 ESV

> Then God said, “Let us make man in our ***image***, after our ***likeness***. And let them have dominion over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the heavens and over the livestock and over all the earth and over every creeping thing that creeps on the earth.”

Later we are told that God is spirit and there was no form to see when he spoke to the Israelites on the mountain

Deuteronomy 4:15 ESV

> Therefore watch yourselves very carefully. Since you saw no form on the day that the LORD spoke to you at Horeb out of the midst of the fire

John 4:24 ESV

> God is spirit, and those who worship him must worship in spirit and truth.

The Hebrew word for image צֶלֶם means resemblance and also representative figure which clearly refers to the physical aspect.

Again the Hebrew word for likeness צֶלֶם also refers to shape,model and resemblance which alludes to physical as well as spiritual attributes

As much as has been said that God is Spirit and has no form in a number of texts it becomes difficult to understand the form of Adam considering that he had a physical aspect to his nature

In light of the description in both Deuteronomy and John how then could one understand the form and likeness in the Genesis text?